# How to display HKDocumentSample retrieved from HealthKit in iOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, healthkit

My goal is to get the health records (CDA) from healthkit store and display it on my app (if not possible, Is there anyway to redirect from my app to Apple's Health App -> Health Records?)

I have already retrieved health records (HKDocumentSample) from the healthkit store using HKDocumentQuery, however I wasn't able to find a way to display it on my app.

[Please click here to view my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9fu0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to build your own visualization for CDA documents because there is no API you can use to display them.

Comment: Is there any way for me to redirect from my app to Apple's Health App -> health records?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Alright! I think i will just create my own visualization of CDA